# How can i inject my Retrofit DataService using Dagger2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, retrofit, rx-java, dagger-2

In my MVP architecture i have Retrofit Instance

```
public class RetrofitInstance {
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";

    /**
     * Create an instance of Retrofit object
     * */
    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

And DataService for it

```
public interface GetNoticeDataService {
    @GET("weather?appid=0194877ecdcac230396a119c01d46100")
    Observable<NoticeList> getNoticeData(@Query("lat") double lat , @Query("lon") double lon );
}
```

Also i have DataInteractor which is using RxJava Observable service to call api

```
public class GetNoticeIntractorImpl implements MainContract.GetNoticeIntractor {
    private LatLng getloc(){
        return currentLocation;
    }
    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    @Override
    public void getNoticeArrayList(final OnFinishedListener onFinishedListener) {

        /** Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
        GetNoticeDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetNoticeDataService.class);
        /** Using RxJava Observable response to handle retrofit api*/
        if(currentLocation!=null) {
            service.getNoticeData(getloc().latitude, getloc().longitude)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(items -> onFinishedListener.onFinished(items.getNoticeArrayList(), items.getMain(), items.getWind()), onFinishedListener::onFailure);

        }
    }

}
```

Here is presenter

```
public class MainPresenterImpl implements MainContract.presenter, MainContract.GetNoticeIntractor.OnFinishedListener {
 private MainContract.MainView mainView;
        private MainContract.GetNoticeIntractor getNoticeIntractor;
        @Inject
        public MainPresenterImpl(MainContract.MainView mainView, MainContract.GetNoticeIntractor getNoticeIntractor) {
            this.mainView = mainView;
            this.getNoticeIntractor = getNoticeIntractor;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {

            mainView = null;

        }

        @Override
        public void onRefreshButtonClick() {

            if(mainView != null){
                mainView.showProgress();
            }
            getNoticeIntractor.getNoticeArrayList(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void requestDataFromServer() {
            getNoticeIntractor.getNoticeArrayList(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onFinished(ArrayList<Notice> noticeArrayList, Main main, Wind wind) {
            if(mainView != null){
                mainView.setDataToRecyclerView(noticeArrayList,main,wind);
                mainView.hideProgress();
            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            if(mainView != null){
                mainView.onResponseFailure(t);
                mainView.hideProgress();
            }
        }
    }
```

And MainContract

```
public interface MainContract {
    /**
     * Call when user interact with the view and other when view OnDestroy()
     * */
    interface presenter{

        void onDestroy();

        void onRefreshButtonClick();

        void requestDataFromServer();

    }

    /**
     * showProgress() and hideProgress() would be used for displaying and hiding the progressBar
     * while the setDataToRecyclerView and onResponseFailure is fetched from the GetNoticeInteractorImpl class
     **/
    interface MainView {

        void showProgress();

        void hideProgress();

        void setDataToRecyclerView(ArrayList<Notice> noticeArrayList, Main main, Wind wind);

        void onResponseFailure(Throwable throwable);

    }

    /**
     * Intractors are classes built for fetching data from your database, web services, or any other data source.
     **/
    interface GetNoticeIntractor {

        interface OnFinishedListener {
            void onFinished(ArrayList<Notice> noticeArrayList, Main main, Wind wind);
            void onFailure(Throwable t);
        }
        void getNoticeArrayList(OnFinishedListener onFinishedListener);

    }
}
```

Adapter for MyActivity

```
public class NoticeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoticeAdapter.EmployeeViewHolder> {

    private static Wind wind;
    private static ArrayList<Notice> dataList;
    private static Main main;
    private Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    public static String date;
    private Context mContext;

    private RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener;
    public NoticeAdapter(ArrayList<Notice> dataList, Main main, Wind wind, RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener,Context context) {
        NoticeAdapter.dataList = dataList;
        NoticeAdapter.main = main;
        NoticeAdapter.wind = wind;
        this.recyclerItemClickListener = recyclerItemClickListener;
        this.mContext=context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EmployeeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_view_row, parent, false);
        return new EmployeeViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EmployeeViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        setDate(currentTime.toString().substring(0,currentTime.toString().length()-18));
        if(getAddressMap()!=null){holder.txtNoticeAddress.setText("Loc: "+getAddressMap());}else{holder.txtNoticeAddress.setText("Loc: Unknown location");}
        holder.imageIcon.setImageURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.locweather/drawable/i"+dataList.get(position).getIcon()));
        holder.txtNoticeWind.setText("Wind: "+roundUp(+wind.getSpeed())+"m/s, "+arrow());
        holder.txtNoticeTempMain.setText(roundUp(+main.getTemp())+"°C");
        holder.txtNoticeWeather.setText(dataList.get(position).getWeather()+" : "+dataList.get(position).getInfo());
        holder.txtNoticeTemp.setText("Feels: "+roundUp(+main.getFeelsLike())+"°C ");
        holder.txtNoticeTime.setText(date);
        holder.txtNoticeHumidity.setText("Humidity: "+main.getHumidity()+"%");
        holder.txtNoticePressure.setText("Pressure: "+main.getPressure()+"hPa");
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            recyclerItemClickListener.onItemClick();
            saveNoticeList(mContext,dataList); });
        holder.saveButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            recyclerItemClickListener.onItemClick();
            saveNoticeList(mContext,dataList); });
    }

    private static String getAddressMap() {
        return MapsActivity.addressMap;
    }

    private static void setDate(String date) {
        NoticeAdapter.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }
    private static LatLng getloc(){
        return currentLocation;
    }

    class EmployeeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageIcon;
        Button saveButton;
        TextView txtNoticeWeather, txtNoticeTempMain,txtNoticeTemp, txtNoticeHumidity,txtNoticeAddress,txtNoticePressure,txtNoticeWind,txtNoticeTime;

        EmployeeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            saveButton=itemView.findViewById(R.id.save_button);
            imageIcon=itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_icon);
            txtNoticeTime= itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_time);
            txtNoticeWind= itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_notice_wind);
            txtNoticeAddress=  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_notice_title);
            txtNoticeWeather =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_notice_weather);
            txtNoticeTemp =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_notice_temp);
            txtNoticeHumidity =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_notice_humidity);
            txtNoticePressure =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_notice_pressure);
            txtNoticeTempMain =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_notice_temp_main);
        }
    }
    private static void saveNoticeList(Context context, List<Notice> noticeList) {
        if (context != null && noticeList != null) {
            WeatherData weatherData = new WeatherData(getAddressMap(), wind.getSpeed(), wind.getDeg(), dataList.get(0).getIcon(), dataList.get(0).getInfo(), dataList.get(0).getWeather(), main.getTemp(), main.getFeelsLike(), main.getHumidity(), main.getPressure(), date, getloc().latitude, getloc().longitude);
            WeatherDatabase.getInstance(context)
                    .weatherDao()
                    .save(weatherData);
        }
    }
```

How can i inject this DataService to my Interactor by using Dagger2? Should i use Singleton or Component or something else?
I'll be glad of any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you want to keep your `RetrofitInstance` singleton available for now, at least until you have migrated all Retrofit uses to Dagger 2.

In order to inject an interface, or a class whose constructor you don't control, you need to use a `Module`.  This tells Dagger how to create instances of that class or interface given some dependencies:

```
@Module
public class WebServiceModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Retrofit provideRetrofit() {
        // This method tells Dagger all it needs to know about creating
        // a Retrofit instance. This will be replaced by something closer
        // to BWappsandmore's answer after RetrofitInstance is no longer needed.
        return RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    GetNoticeDataService provideGetNoticeDataService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(GetNoticeDataService.class);
    }
```

This module can then be included in your `Component`, which will in turn create any objects it knows how to create, either from modules, `@BindsInstance` values passed into your component factory method, or classes with `@Inject` constructors.  Since you control your interactor's constructor, you can simply annotate it with `@Inject`:

```
// @Reusable or @Singleton if you only need one interactor of this type.
public class GetNoticeInteractorImpl implements MainContract.GetNoticeInteractor {
    private GetNoticeDataService service

    @Inject
    GetNoticeInteractorImpl(GetNoticeDataService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    private LatLng getloc(){
        return currentLocation;
    }
    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    @Override
    public void getNoticeArrayList(final OnFinishedListener onFinishedListener) {

        // Our service was injected in the constructor, so there
        // is no need to create it here.

        // You might also consider injecting your schedulers in the future
        // for unit testing.
        if(currentLocation!=null) {
            service.getNoticeData(getloc().latitude, getloc().longitude)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(items -> onFinishedListener.onFinished(items.getNoticeArrayList(), items.getMain(), items.getWind()), onFinishedListener::onFailure);

        }
    }

}

@Module
abstract class AnotherModule { // or interface
    @Binds
    abstract MainContract.GetNoticeInteractor bindGetNoticeInteractor(GetNoticeInteractorImpl implementation);
}
```

Of course, this is useless if you can't ultimately access your interactor.  Since you don't even create your `Activity` classes, you need to request injection from a `Component`.  In Android apps, this is typically created within the `Application` object in `onCreate()`.

```
@Component(modules = {WebServicesModule.class, AnotherModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        AppComponent create(@BindsInstance Application application); // or whatever
    }

    void bindMainActivity(MainActivity activity);
}

// Probably not a singleton, but if you create an activity scope later, this might use that scope.
class MainPresenter {
    @Inject
    public MainPresenter(MainContract.GetNoticeInteractor interactor) {
        this.getNoticeInteractor = interactor
    }
    // ...
}

class MainActivity {
    @Inject
    MainPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        somehowGetComponent().inject(this);
        super(savedInstanceState);
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now, since your `MainActivity` requires a `MainPresenter`, Dagger will create one for you when you request injection.  This in turn requires a `GetNoticeInteractor`, which requires `GetNoticeInteractorImpl`, and so forth, and Dagger will take care of all of this behind the scenes.

If your presenter's constructor requires other arguments (such as a View), it might be simpler for now for MainActivity to request injection directly into the presenter.  Ultimately, you will want all of your `inject(SomeClass target)` methods to refer to Activities, Services, and such, since there is no other way to inject those until your `minSdkVersion` is 28 or higher.

Comment: Yes, im using recyclerview and it adapter for activity, i can add presenter and adapter for better understnding

Comment: Already add, check pls and edit for my situation deeply if u can, https://github.com/evgenyuliganets/LocWeather here is my repository if u need

Comment: what is .inject(this) and where it declared?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Module
object WebServiceModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesGetNoticeDataService(retrofit: Retrofit): GetNoticeDataService =
        retrofit.create<GetNoticeDataService>(GetNoticeDataService::class.java)

    @Provides
    fun providesGsonConverterFactory(): GsonConverterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create()

    @Provides
    fun providesOkHttpClient(loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient =
        OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()

    @Provides
    fun providesOkHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor =
        HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }

    @Provides
    fun provideRxJava2CallAdapterFactory(): RxJava2CallAdapterFactory =
        RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()

    @Provides
    fun providesRetrofit(
        client: OkHttpClient,
        converterFactory: GsonConverterFactory,
        adapterFactory: RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
    ): Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()        
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL) 
        .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(adapterFactory)
        .client(client)
        .build()
}
```

Comment: is it kotlin? i need solution for java

Comment: @sippinman it is in Kotlin, but I think it it easy to either convert it to Java or include it in your project as it is - Android Studio makes it possible.

Comment: can you please convert it and add it here? because i've never use kotlin and i cant decompile it in my project.